# Bad SSH2 mac spec EC2

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to disable any weak ciphers/algorithms in my ec2 instances. And I have added following lines in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
...
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
MACs hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
...
```

And when I try to restart the `sshd` service, it is not re-starting properly. So I did;

```
sshd -t
```

And I got the following error:

> Bad SSH2 mac spec 'hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com'

Can somehelp help me how to fix this?

The sshd version is `OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021`

Answer (score 5):

Support for the RIPE-MD160 HMAC algorithm  was **removed from OpenSSH in 2017** in the [7.6 release](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) so you might want to check the publication date and how old the source is to support your decision on what algorithms you want to include.

According to the manual [`man  sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MACs) the list of available MAC algorithms can be obtained using `ssh -Q mac`.

Make a selection from those.

The now defunct cypherli.st recommended  the following as strong MAC algorithms:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

and other settings:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

But you might want to confirm those as well.

Comment: Is there a way I can identify if my `MACs` or `Ciphers` are weak or strong?

Comment: OpenSSH defaults are tuned for compatibility, using settings that are still considered secure for general purposes but they also do not limit clients to use only the "best"  cryptographic security. Generally elliptic curves, AES are considered good and longer keys are better than shorter. Cryptography is an ever evolving field of studies and what is considered weak and strong also evolves with research and scientific breakthroughs.  That is better discussed at https://security.stackexchange.com/  - Also: https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: This worked great - listing the mac algorithms with ssh -Q mac showed the configured hmac-ripemd169 was missing for me.

Comment: no `ssh -Q` option with version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze8, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010